# Hyperledger Fabric: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: TCP Read failed

Tags: tcp

I have two servers. One is using to build app service and the other is using to build hyperledger fabric network. When i request from app service to blockchain network then sometime i have some problem like below:

[client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: TCP Read failed
at new createStatusError (/home/user/server/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
at /home/user/server/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15

[Orderer.js]: sendBroadcast - on error: "Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: TCP Read failed\n at createStatusError (/home/user/server/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)\n at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/home/user/server/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:270:19)\n at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/home/user/server/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:248:8)\n at /home/user/server/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:804:12".

Is anyone know to solved this issue. Thanks so much. (sorry for my bad english)